# How can I get this angular animation to repeat?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-animations

I'm new to Angular and I made an animation that starts on enter. Once it's done I want it to jump back to the original position and slide down again, I'd like it to loop infinitely.

Here's what my animation looks like right now:

```
  animations: [
    trigger('slideImg', [
      state('off', style({ transform: 'translate(550%, -203%)'})),
      transition(':enter', [
      style({ transform: 'translate(650%, -303%)' }),
        animate(600)
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!